# Xcode 6 throws clang error while compiling

Tags: xcode, ios8, clang, xcode6

I have recently updated my Xcode to version 6.0 (6A313). Now, during the compilation I get the following error:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-wall'
```

From [Clang Compiler User's Manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html), I found out that this flag is responsible for **enabling all warnings**. I have also read many posts on the temporary fix for Apple LLVM Compiler for Xcode 5.1, where users would downgrade all clang errors to warnings with:

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future easy_install ExtensionName
```

However, that does not help me, as there is no such extension as "all". So I am stuck at this point and any suggestions would be appreciated. 
Also, I have upgraded to **Ruby 2.1.1** (from 2.0.x), but that did not seem to help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is `-Wall`, not `-wall`.

Comment: so where might it be? I did not write any of these scripts, as everything was taken "out of the box". I am not sure how do I go by changing these arguments.

Comment: @mike.tihonchik You could attempt to open the Xcode project file (a `.pbproj` file, if memory serves) with a text editor and searching for it.